# How to extract a a substring in a within a for loop in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I found quite a few related queries, but none that addresses this exact point and I regret I am stuck.
I have a txt file with a list of strings that have assorted junk in the beginning and end with the 23 characters I need to grab and finally a double quote that I need to discard.

From various examples I have gotten the the following draft, but the string extract (that works in the top part, fails when used within the for statement:

```
set a=This message needs changed. 
echo caput
echo %a% 
rem set i=globalvariableastest
set a=%a:~-9% 
echo %a%

pause

echo "now for file"


for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (ioschi.txt) do (
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
echo %%i
set j=%%i
echo !j!
set k="!j!:~-23!"
echo !k!
)

pause
code here
```

While on the top non recursive part I get the expected clipping, within the *for* statement the resulting echo is

```
"full string:~-23!"
```

Would appreciate your help on how to run string extraction within a *for* statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is effectively just an unwanted additional **`!`** character, `set k="!j!:~-23!"` should read `Set "k=!j:~-23!"`. You'll note that I have not included hardcoded enclosing doublequotes in the variable value, it is better practice to instead doublequote your variables in use, as necessary.

Here's how I'd generally perform this type of task, i.e. output the last 23 characters of each non empty line in a file:

```bat
@For /F UseBackQDelims^=^ EOL^= %%I In ("ioschi.txt")Do @(
    Set "line=%%I"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo "!line:~-23!"
    EndLocal
)
@Pause
```

I have used `UseBackQ` as this allows me to always doublequote the filename to read, protecting any spaces or problematic characters in its name and/or path. I have also used a strange looking method with caret, **`^`**, escapes, for the `Delims` and `EOL` options. This is because `For /F` loops always exclude any line which begins with a semi-colon, **`;`**. This method defines that 'beginning' character as none and allows every line to be read, regardless of its first character. Note that empty lines are always excluded from the output too.

Comment: Thanks Compo for your generous sharing!  Much obliged.  Unfortunately my upvote does not show here because of my newness :(

Comment: If the answer has solved your issue, you do not upvote it, you accept it. You can do that by simply clicking on the large grayed out check mark to the left of the selected answer.